# display array from multiple json objects with ajax & jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have multiple objects similar to the one below. I want to display the mealReviews: [] Array from all the multiple json objects into a $('#mealDetails').html().

```
 {
"_id": {
    "$oid": "59ef162f7afc7636"
},
"mealIDa": "ACT",
"mealIDb": "TMNT2",
"title": "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles 2 The Secret of the Ooze",
"description": "The Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles (Mark Caso, Michelan Sisti, Leif Tilden, Kenn Troum) again battle their archenemy, the rogue ninja Shredder (Francois Chau). Shredder attempts revenge by obtaining the same radioactive ooze that created the Turtles and unleashing two new monstrous mutants: Tokka, an oversized snapping turtle, and Rahzar, a fearsome wolf-like creature. When Shredder plans to use the remaining ooze on himself, the Turtles must harness their ninja fighting skills to stop him.",
"releaseDate": "March 22, 1991",
"language": "English",
"subtitle": false,
"srt": "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles II The Secret of the Ooze.srt",
"director": "Michael Pressman",
"actors": "Paige Turco \"April O'Neil\", Vanilla Ice, Michelan Sisti \"Michelangelo, Soho Man\", Robbie Rist \"Michelangelo\", Kevin Clash \"Splinter\"",
"studio": "Golden Harvest Company, New Line Cinema, Northshore Investments Ltd.",
"hrs": 1,
"mins": 28,
"ratings": "PG \u2013 Parents Cautioned",
"dateAdded": "2017-07-18T20:59:17.473Z",
"mealReviews": [
    {
        "username": "dwaynekshrn",
        "accountType": "cop",
        "subject": "Lucky Award Winners",
        "rating": "1",
        "review": "I really think this movies deserves an academy award",
        "reviewDate": "2017-07-25T23:29:53.371Z"
    },
    {
        "username": "dwaynekshrn",
        "accountType": "cop",
        "subject": "One on the shot clock",
        "rating": "1",
        "review": "He shoots, he scores!",
        "reviewDate": "2017-07-24T22:58:17.622Z"
    },
    {
        "username": "shaolinkyle",
        "accountType": "monk",
        "subject": "In da house",
        "rating": "1",
        "review": "Shaolin Kyle is in the house!",
        "reviewDate": "2017-07-24T22:47:56.056Z"
    },
    {
        "username": "dwaynekshrn",
        "accountType": "cop",
        "subject": "Political Spectrum",
        "rating": "1",
        "review": "is dope son!",
        "reviewDate": "2017-07-24T22:51:51.106Z"
    }
   ]
}
```

I am retrieving the data from ajax request but it doesn't seem to be returning the data when I check it with a console.log. It works when I target a specific object but when I try to get the same data from all the objects, I'm drawing a blank.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
  $('#mealDetails').empty();
  // test to see if retrieving data
  console.log(data.title);
  var reviews = [];
  var output = '<div>';
  $.each(data.mealReviews, function(key, value) {
    output += '<div class="row">';
    output += '<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-
    offset-1"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/' + 
     this.accountType +'.png" width="200" height="200" alt="">';
    output += '<p>By <a>'+ this.username +'</a> '+ this.reviewDate +'</p></div>';
    output += '<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8"><div class="row">';
    output += '<h2>'+ this.rating +'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> '+ this.subject +'</h2>';
    output += '<p class="textFormat">'+ this.review +'</p></div></div>';
    output += '</div>';
  });

output += '</div>';
reviews.push(output);
$('#mealDetails').html(output);


},
error:function(xhr,status,err){
  console.log('nah bruh thats a no go');
}

  });
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for.. Are you receiving the data in AJAX call success response???

Comment: no I'm not recieving the data. It is returning undefined

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`this.accountType` with `value.accountType`.

Means you have to replace all `this.` with `value.` inside the `$.each(....)`

Comment: my data is returning undefined. How would you go about solving that?

Comment: wrap your code with if(data != undefined){ YOUR_CODE }

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/j4r3dcxr/

```js
var data1 ={
 "_id": {
  "$oid": "59ef162f7afc7636"
 },
 "mealIDa": "ACT",
 "mealIDb": "TMNT2",
 "title": "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles 2 The Secret of the Ooze",
 "description": "The Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles (Mark Caso, Michelan Sisti, Leif Tilden, Kenn Troum) again battle their archenemy, the rogue ninja Shredder (Francois Chau). Shredder attempts revenge by obtaining the same radioactive ooze that created the Turtles and unleashing two new monstrous mutants: Tokka, an oversized snapping turtle, and Rahzar, a fearsome wolf-like creature. When Shredder plans to use the remaining ooze on himself, the Turtles must harness their ninja fighting skills to stop him.",
 "releaseDate": "March 22, 1991",
 "language": "English",
 "subtitle": false,
 "srt": "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles II The Secret of the Ooze.srt",
 "director": "Michael Pressman",
 "actors": "Paige Turco \"April O'Neil\", Vanilla Ice, Michelan Sisti \"Michelangelo, Soho Man\", Robbie Rist \"Michelangelo\", Kevin Clash \"Splinter\"",
 "studio": "Golden Harvest Company, New Line Cinema, Northshore Investments Ltd.",
 "hrs": 1,
 "mins": 28,
 "ratings": "PG \u2013 Parents Cautioned",
 "dateAdded": "2017-07-18T20:59:17.473Z",
 "mealReviews": [{
   "username": "dwaynekshrn",
   "accountType": "cop",
   "subject": "Lucky Award Winners",
   "rating": "1",
   "review": "I really think this movies deserves an academy award",
   "reviewDate": "2017-07-25T23:29:53.371Z"
  },
  {
   "username": "dwaynekshrn",
   "accountType": "cop",
   "subject": "One on the shot clock",
   "rating": "1",
   "review": "He shoots, he scores!",
   "reviewDate": "2017-07-24T22:58:17.622Z"
  },
  {
   "username": "shaolinkyle",
   "accountType": "monk",
   "subject": "In da house",
   "rating": "1",
   "review": "Shaolin Kyle is in the house!",
   "reviewDate": "2017-07-24T22:47:56.056Z"
  },
  {
   "username": "dwaynekshrn",
   "accountType": "cop",
   "subject": "Political Spectrum",
   "rating": "1",
   "review": "is dope son!",
   "reviewDate": "2017-07-24T22:51:51.106Z"
  }
 ]
};

var data2 ={
 "_id": {
  "$oid": "59ef162f7afc7636"
 },
 "mealIDa": "ACT",
 "mealIDb": "TMNT2",
 "title": "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles 2 The Secret of the Ooze",
 "description": "The Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles (Mark Caso, Michelan Sisti, Leif Tilden, Kenn Troum) again battle their archenemy, the rogue ninja Shredder (Francois Chau). Shredder attempts revenge by obtaining the same radioactive ooze that created the Turtles and unleashing two new monstrous mutants: Tokka, an oversized snapping turtle, and Rahzar, a fearsome wolf-like creature. When Shredder plans to use the remaining ooze on himself, the Turtles must harness their ninja fighting skills to stop him.",
 "releaseDate": "March 22, 1991",
 "language": "English",
 "subtitle": false,
 "srt": "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles II The Secret of the Ooze.srt",
 "director": "Michael Pressman",
 "actors": "Paige Turco \"April O'Neil\", Vanilla Ice, Michelan Sisti \"Michelangelo, Soho Man\", Robbie Rist \"Michelangelo\", Kevin Clash \"Splinter\"",
 "studio": "Golden Harvest Company, New Line Cinema, Northshore Investments Ltd.",
 "hrs": 1,
 "mins": 28,
 "ratings": "PG \u2013 Parents Cautioned",
 "dateAdded": "2017-07-18T20:59:17.473Z",
 "mealReviews": [{
   "username": "dwaynekshrn",
   "accountType": "cop",
   "subject": "Lucky Award Winners",
   "rating": "1",
   "review": "I really think this movies deserves an academy award",
   "reviewDate": "2017-07-25T23:29:53.371Z"
  },
  {
   "username": "dwaynekshrn",
   "accountType": "cop",
   "subject": "One on the shot clock",
   "rating": "1",
   "review": "He shoots, he scores!",
   "reviewDate": "2017-07-24T22:58:17.622Z"
  },
  {
   "username": "shaolinkyle",
   "accountType": "monk",
   "subject": "In da house",
   "rating": "1",
   "review": "Shaolin Kyle is in the house!",
   "reviewDate": "2017-07-24T22:47:56.056Z"
  },
  {
   "username": "dwaynekshrn",
   "accountType": "cop",
   "subject": "Political Spectrum",
   "rating": "1",
   "review": "is dope son!",
   "reviewDate": "2017-07-24T22:51:51.106Z"
  }
 ]
};

getData = function(data){
 var reviews = [];
  var output = '<div>';
  $.each(data.mealReviews, function(key, value) {
    output += '<div class="row">';
    output += '<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/' + 
     data.mealReviews[key].accountType +'.png" width="200" height="200" alt="">';
    output += '<p>By <a>'+ this.username +'</a> '+ data.mealReviews[key].reviewDate +'</p></div>';
    output += '<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8"><div class="row">';
    output += '<h2>'+ this.rating +'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> '+ data.mealReviews[key].subject +'</h2>';
    output += '<p class="textFormat">'+ data.mealReviews[key].review +'</p></div></div>';
    output += '</div>';
  });

  output += '</div>';
  reviews.push(output);
  $('body').append(output);
}

getData(data1);
getData(data2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure whether you are looking for this or not...
Instead of AJAX call I have kept the data in two different variables and passed those data to a function ( whatever you have it in your AJAX success method ).

Instead of doing .html to body or particular container(id/class), I have used .append() to append the data.

Comment: my data is returning undefined. How would you go about solving that?

Answer (score 0):

each is looping with an anonymous method, so `this` is lost in context to what you're actually intending here.  You should use the value param in your $.each loop to refer to the item that is being iterated over.

```
var reviews = [];
var output = '<div>';
$.each( data.mealReviews, function( key, value ) {
output += '<div class="row">';
output += '<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/' + 
 value.accountType +'.png" width="200" height="200" alt="">';
output += '<p>By <a>'+ value.username +'</a> '+ value.reviewDate +'</p></div>';
output += '<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8"><div class="row">';
output += '<h2>'+ value.rating +'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> '+ value.subject +'</h2>';
output += '<p class="textFormat">'+ value.review +'</p></div></div>';
output += '</div>';
});

output += '</div>';
reviews.push(output);
$( '#mealDetails' ).html( output );
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8bc3hdqp/

**EDIT**: 
If you're meaning that your return actually has an array of multiple objects like the one you displayed, then you would loop over those and then loop over the contents:

```
var reviews = [];
var output = '<div>';
$.each( data, function( k, v ) {
    $.each( data[k].mealReviews, function( key, value ) {
        output += '<div class="row">';
        output += '<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/' + value.accountType +'.png" width="200" height="200" alt="">';
        output += '<p>By <a>'+ value.username +'</a> '+ value.reviewDate +'</p></div>';
        output += '<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8"><div class="row">';
        output += '<h2>'+ value.rating +'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> '+ value.subject +'</h2>';
        output += '<p class="textFormat">'+ value.review +'</p></div></div>';
        output += '</div>';
    });
});

output += '</div>';
reviews.push(output);
$( '#mealDetails' ).html( output );
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8bc3hdqp/1/

You can try console logging the object by converting it to a string with console.log( JSON.stringify( data ) ); if that helps in debugging things for you ( not sure what you mean by you're not seeing anything in the response ).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I meant the data is returning "undefined". Before actually returning the divs, how would I go about returning the data in the first place?

Comment: Well your console.log is doing data.title, try just doing data to see if anything at all is coming back.  Inspect the XHR request response in your console to see if there's any additional information that might let you know why it's failing.  Then the last thing would be that it's not related to your js at all - it's from whatever is serving the content, so if it's your own API check the code there to see why it might be sending a response that is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. At first my issue was that all the objects did not have the same data in the mealReviews Array. Some had an array with objects while others had a string which crashed my app. So I made an if statement filtering only the mealReviews with an array. Then I made another if statement that only displayed the arrays that did not have empty objects.

```
 $.get(url).done(function(data){
 var reviews = [];
 var output = '<div>';
 $.each( data, function( k, v ) {
 if (data[k].mealReviews instanceof Array){
 $.each( data[k].mealReviews, function( key, value ) {
   if(value.username){
  output += '<div class="thumbnail row">';
  output += '<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/' + value.accountType +'.png" width="200" height="200" alt="">';
  output += '<p>By <a>'+ value.username +'</a> '+ value.reviewDate +'</p></div>';
  output += '<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8"><div class="row">';
  output += '<h2>'+ value.rating +'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> '+ value.subject +'</h2>';
  output += '<p class="textFormat">'+ value.review +'</p></div></div>';
  output += '</div>';
  }
 });
}

});

 output += '</div>';
 reviews.push(output);
 $( '#mealDetails' ).prepend(output);
});
```